# Replace Space in DNN Friendly URLs

Tags: dotnetnuke, friendly-url

I'm working on a site running DNN 7, and I'm trying to format my URLs. In my web.config file I changed the format to HumanFriendly URLs like so:

```
<add name="iFinity.FriendlyUrl" type="iFinity.DNN.Modules.FriendlyUrl.DNNFriendlyUrlProvider,
iFinity.FriendlyUrlProvider" includePageName="true" regexMatch="[^\+a-zA-Z0-9 _-]"
urlFormat="HumanFriendly" redirectUnfriendly="true" doNotRedirect="SearchResults;" 
checkForDupUrls="true" forceLowerCase="true" redirectWrongCase="false" replaceSpaceWith="-" 
logCacheMessages="false" pageExtensionUsage="never" />
```

The rewrite is working fine, except one problem. On pages that have a space, for example we have a page titled, "Who We Are" I want the URL to be who-we-are, and the URL is generating as whoweare. What do I need to add in order to change that? I've been digging all morning and can't find anything about it.

Thank you in advance for any help, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The iFinity Friendly URL functionality has been merged into the DNN core and is no longer updated.
[http://www.ifinity.com.au/2013/07/22/DNN_71_and_Url_Master](http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/6)

The above post explains how to transition to the new provider.

I uninstalled the iFinity controll, and then used instructions from this page to change the space character:
http://www.christoc.com/Tutorials/All-Tutorials/aid/6